# Convert subquery (that selects record based on ordering) to a JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have this query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM iptable
 WHERE ip = (SELECT ip
               FROM iptable
              WHERE name = 'username'
              ORDER BY date DESC
              LIMIT 0,1
            )
   AND name != 'username'
```

Here's what it does:

- user enters a name (in this case it's *username*)
- the query gets the latest record from *iptable* (IP only)
- it searches *iptable* for **other** users with the returned IP

The query works well, but I'm wondering if it's possible to make it to use JOIN instead of subqueries? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's [almost?] always possible to use a join. Give it a shot, like give it at least 10 minutes of thought/trial, and look at tutorials/references/existing questions as required - and *then* ask a question; be sure to provided what has been attempted and "how it doesn't work" or what is still not understood.

Comment: Or just wait 3 minutes and someone will lay it all out on a plate for you ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting all names that come in on the ip from the most recent ip for a given user.  (I originally misread the query, so this helps.)

The following converts this to an explicit join:

```
select ip.*
from iptable ip join
     (select date, max(ip) as maxip
      from iptable
      where name = 'username'
      group by date
      order by date desc
      limit 1
     ) ips
     on ips.maxip = ip.ip
where is.name <>  'username'
```

(There may be some assumption that names and ips are never NULL.)

I do want to point out, though, that the original version is still doing a join, just not explicitly.

The challenge is getting that most recent ip for a name.  Here is another way, that uses `group_concat` with `substring_index`:

```
select ip.*
from iptable ip join
     (select name,
             substring_index(group_concat(ip order by date desc), ',', 1) as lastip
      from iptable
      where name = 'username'
      group by name
     ) ips
     on ips.lastip = ip.ip
where ips.name <> ip.name
```

Comment: It works, thanks. When using JOIN, it takes 0.0004 seconds longer than my query. I know it's not big, but I tested it on 15 entries, and I'm wondering what'll happen with 15000 or so. Why is it slower? I've read that JOIN's are faster.

Comment: @user1494486 It is [*dependent/correlated subqueries*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/correlated-subqueries.html) that are (in many cases) not able to be optimized: in such degenerate cases - where the subquery cannot be implicitly rewritten in terms of a suitable JOIN - the subquery must be executed for *each row* in the outer query. In your query there is no correlation. Use `EXPLAIN` to see the query plan for both queries - the plan should indicate the expected *time complexity* of the query (i.e. how it will scale; however, the plan *can change* with statistics as the data grows).